# Mathematica - Extract actual data values to calculate expected value

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, probability

I've the below data in variable X. The data is in the form of pair of numbers {a, b}.

a represents the actual value while b represents its frequency in the data set.

```
X = {{20, 30}, {21, 40}, {22, 50}}
```

I want to calculate expected value of this data set.

How can extract out all values of a in a separate data set ?

Answer (score 0):

The expected value is (in non-Mma notation) `sum(x[i]*p[i], i, 1, n)` where `x[i]` is the `i`-th distinct value (i.e., first value in each pair), `p[i]` is the proportion of that value (i.e., second value in each pair divided by the total of all of the second values), and `n` is the number of distinct values of `x` (i.e., the number of pairs). I think this is enough to help you solve it now.